# Calling a module's local function as callback in "request"

Tags: node.js, express, module, request, asynccallback

In my main code, I do the following:

```
var module = require('./module')

module.FooA(module.FooB);
```

`module.js` contains the next code:

```
var request = require('request'); //using of npm "request"

exports.FooB = function(data){ /*operations on data here*/ };

exports.FooA = function(callback){

    var url = some_link;

    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            callback(body);
        };
    });

};
```

The issue is that apparently, `callback(body)` doesn't run even if the conditions meet. `var result = request(url)` followed by `exports.FooB(result)` does the job, but as far as I can see, obviously does not act like a callback, and would produce troubles.

What is the proper way of defining a callback function in such a case? Do I need at all, or it is actually synchronous and I missed to notice it?

Comment: I tried the code you posted and it works fine, the issue is elsewhere. Are you sure you request is 200/OK? Can you try with http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users ?

Comment: @ShanShan I'm sorry, I wasn't entirely clear. This code runs on the backend side, thus if there's a syntax error, it responds with HTTP 500. To test if it works, I send a variable from frontend, modify it in `FooB` and send it back and write it out. The issue is that **despite there's no syntax error**, no changes I've made inn `FooB` ever occured. Thus, I assume its content is not executed.

Comment: Don't assume anything, put console.log at every step, the structure you posted works for me and should work for you too.

Comment: @ShanShan well, you're right - I was a bit naive since this way of debugging has always worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use first function callback params with error, this is an default in node.js core and is google for your project functions.

And like @ShanSan commend, use **console.log**, **console.error** or **console.trace** for debug.

Example:

```
var request = require('request'); //using of npm "request"

exports.FooB = function(error, data){ /*operations on data here*/ };

exports.FooA = function(callback){

    var url = some_link;

    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
          // pass error to callback and if use return you dont need other code block bellow
          console.error('Error in request', error);
          return callback(error, null); 
        } 

        // here run if dont have errors

        // if need more info use the console.log(request); or console.log(body);

        // use error in first param in callback functions 

        callback(null, body);
    });

};
```

Comment: Actually, I found out that the problem was that I missed considering the aysnc nature of requests, and this is why variables weren't sent. `console.log` made me notice. However, if I understood well, your solution provides handling for errors, thus it's great and I mark it as accepted.